# HTML margin percentage update

Tags: html, css

Sorry for my misunderstanding but I can't get how margin works. I read many examples but I don't know how and why it doesn't work for me.

I have the following script written in HTML:

```
<img style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom: 20; margin-left: 3%; margin-right: 10%; margin-right: 5%;" src="\C:\Users\user\Desktop\website\static\rickandmortygif1.gif" style="position:relative; top: 420px; left: 32px;" width="480" height="270" class="rickandmortyGif"></img>
<strong1 style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom: 50%; margin-left: 10%;">I can't believe i actually did this, wow i really need to find</strong1>
```

Now for some reason when I play with the `img` percentages in the margin, it moves the `img`. I don't know why. What I want is to be able to position everything in my code as I want, if I want the image to be higher then I will just change the percentage and it won't affect other elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percentage using the canvas( the size of your screen on which website is open ) 
let suppose your screen size is 1000px now you apply margin:2%; so its calculate 1000px 2% which is 20px approx , so its apply 20px on all side.

and in real life example margin works like, suppose you have 1 box you need to place it a specific place you get to hold a box and place it where you need like, you just moving the box in the room. moving a Element from its actual placement you need to use margin.

```
<div style='float:left;width:50%;'>
<img style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom: 20; margin-left: 3%; 
 margin-right: 10%; margin-right: 5%;" src="\C:\Users\user\Desktop
\website\static\rickandmortygif1.gif" style="position:relative; top:
420px; left: 32px;" width="480" height="270" class="rickandmortyGif">
</img>
</div>
<div style='float:left;width:50%;'>
<strong1 style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom: 50%; margin-left: 
10%;">I can't believe i actually did this, wow i really need to 
find</strong1>
```

Comment: Thanks fotr the answer but do you know why when i change the percentages on the img it moves the text.. its really annoying and idk why its happening

Comment: of course, when you move the box, the box next to you also move, understand so you need an image in the center of the div(box)?

Comment: nah, i want to be able to move the img to a specific locatoon, and the div to other location different from the img, problem is when i move the img the div position changes also, is there any command to cancel it or smt?

Comment: thanks, and last question, do i have to use percentages if i want to position my objects?. so if i upload my website and view it on other computer screen it stays in the same position? or i can use px too, cuz i find it rlly annoying

Comment: @Z.Zadon yes its vary on different screens, so you make the container in percentage but the element in it use px for them so it makes the pixel perfect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185246/discussion-between-z-zadon-and-noni).

Answer (score 1):

Margins create extra space around an element. The percentage is often used to define a size as relative to an element's parent object.

Suppose the image is placed inside a 'div' element, the parent element is the 'div' and based on the size of parent element, it decides its margin values and the image adjust itself.

You can go through MDN [Margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) for better understanding.